# Does Drupal use Cross-Site Request Forgery (CSRF) tokens anywhere?

Tags: drupal, request, csrf

Is there a way to find out if a Drupal instance has a CSRF tokens used anywhere? And how do we find out if those tokens are vulnerable?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[As long as you use the Form API](https://www.drupal.org/node/178896), you can be sure that CSRF tokens are being used in your forms.

Comment: It is true only for the authorized users. What about anonymous users? Drupal doesn't add CSRF token to the forms for anonymous users. The users can be easily redirected to the fake web-site.